# How to revert a buffer without changing active modes?

Tags: buffers

`M-x revert-buffer` resets the active minor modes to the defaults for the underlying file. How can I preserve the minor modes active while reverting the buffer?

My attempt so far:

```
(defun revert ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((active-modes minor-mode-list))
   (revert-buffer t t)
   (setq minor-mode-list active-modes)))
```

This seemed broadly reasonable. Save minor-mode-list, revert the buffer, setq to restore. Calling (revert) seems to be exactly equivalent to calling revert-buffer and I'm not sure how to debug this.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're missing the third argument to [revert-buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reverting.html):

> Optional third argument PRESERVE-MODES non-nil means don’t alter
>   the files modes.  Normally we reinitialize them using ‘normal-mode’.

That should do exactly what you want, without requiring any further book-keeping on your part.

Comment: That's a good observation. Passing another t along works nicely, thanks!